# Print Text in dlib window

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I would like to know how can I print some strings in a dlib library window for some seconds allowing the user to read them properly. So far I found the following method in the API:

```
const rectangle r;
win.add_overlay(r,rgb_pixel(255,0,0), "Someone smiled!");
```

which just prints for one frame. I would like to get something like the Opencv method 
`void displayOverlay(const string& winname, const string& text, int delayms=0 )`. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple of years old, but I had the same problem and I hope this helps people.

I managed to display a rectangle and text beside it doing the following:

```
win.add_overlay(image_window::overlay_rect(rect, rgb_pixel(255, 0, 0), "text"));
```

I found this in a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552082/write-a-text-in-dlib-image). I set the rectangle to a negative position and size to 0,0.