# Write a text in dlib image

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

i'm using dlib for face detection and i would like to write a text in the image. 
i've tried this `win.add_overlay(dets, rgb_pixel(255,0,0),"test" );`
but it's not working

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [dlib documentation](http://dlib.net/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets_abstract.h.html#image_window), the `add_overlay` method takes an overlay as a parameter. Since you want to display rectangles you have to create an `overlay_rect`. You should try the following code :

`win.add_overlay(dlib::image_window::overlay_rect(dets, rgb_pixel(255,0,0),"test" ));`

dlib documentation is really well done (props to Davis King) you should take some time to read and understand it.

Comment: I'm looking for the equivalent python code but the api seems different: any ideas?

Comment: `cv2.putText(frame,'text',(50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.2,(0,0,255),3)`

Answer (score 0):

As of this [PR](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/pull/2270), you can write text directly onto the image (the method proposed above relies on a gui window, so the text is not written onto the image, ie. the image is not modified).

You can use it like this:

```cpp
draw_string(image, point{10, 15}, string{"cat"}, rgb_pixel{255, 255, 255});
```

It also accepts any [`dlib::bdf_font`](http://dlib.net/dlib/gui_widgets/fonts_abstract.h.html#bdf_font).